# Get intermediate results of Gurobi optimization

Tags: python, optimization, gurobi

I'm using Gurobi 7.0.2 (+ Python 3.5, i.e., `gurobipy`) to solve some hard optimization problems (MIPs). Finding optimal results usually takes days or even weeks. It's possible to interrupt Gurobi before having found an optimal solution, i.e., Gap > 0%, and the currently best solution will be returned.

However, it would be much nicer to retrieve such an intermediate result with Gap > 0% but without completely interrupting Gurobi. Gurobi should continue trying to improve the current solution, but I could already start working with the intermediate solution.

Is this possible somehow? If not, please add it to the next Gurobi version.

Comment: Look up [callbacks](https://www.gurobi.com/documentation/7.0/refman/py_callbacks.html) where you would define *when* some callback is called (e.g. new best solution; maybe start [here](https://www.gurobi.com/documentation/7.0/refman/py_model_cbgetsolution.html#pythonmethod:Model.cbGetSolution)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write a callback function, with where==MIPSOL.  Then call `Model.cbGetSolution()`; see the sample code for [Model.cbGetSolution()](http://www.gurobi.com/documentation/current/refman/py_model_cbgetsolution.html).